# How to set owner password to existing PDF files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

Does anyone have an idea about how to set owner password to existing PDF files?

Answer (score 1):

CGPDFContextCreate takes a dictionary in which you can pass a owner password as one of the attributes.

The details for CGPDFContxtCreate you'll find in Apple's reference documents at:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFContextCreate

And the password setting information you'll find in Apple's docs here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Auxiliary_Dictionary_Keys